# sqlite3.OperationalError about an incomplete input-

Tags: python, sqlite, operationalerror

I have an operational SQLite3 error. Previously when I have had this error it has been about brackets or something like that but I can't see what is causing the problem here.

```
//declared the table:

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (appointmentID, clientID, dentistID)")

//I have a program here to take the inputs

c.execute('''INSERT INTO ids (appointmentID, clientID, dentistID) VALUES (?,?,?),''', (appointmentID, clientID, dentistID))
```

Here is the full error traceback:

```
// this is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/barna/OneDrive/Documents/A- Level/NEA/fixing `error.py`", line 124, in <module>
    login()
  File "C:/Users/barna/OneDrive/Documents/A- Level/NEA/fixing `error.py`", line 33, in login
    checkIds(foundID)
  File "C:/Users/barna/OneDrive/Documents/A- Level/NEA/fixing `error.py`", line 84, in checkIds
    c.execute("INSERT INTO IDs (appointmentID, clientID, dentistID) VALUES (?,?,?),", (appointmentID, clientID, dentistID))
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Why is there a comma at the end of your query?